# "WARN peerdependencies" while installing Semantic-UI

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, semantic-ui

I followed all the instructions posted on the Semantic-UI website in order to install the framework, namely:

- Install node: I have confirmed it was installed properly by running node -v, to which I get "v0.12.7". Node is installed in /usr/local/include and I have already unpdated the $PATH to reflect the changes.
- Install gulp: I ran sudo npm install -g gulp to install gulp globally in /usr/local/lib/node_modules (non-sudo command gave me errors and suggested the sudo command)

I cd to my project folder and run "npm install semantic-ui --save", to which I get:

```
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency better-console@* included from semantic-ui will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency del@* included from semantic-ui will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency extend@* included from semantic-ui will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency gulp@* included from semantic-ui will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency gulp-autoprefixer@* included from semantic-ui will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency gulp-chmod@* included from semantic-ui will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency gulp-clone@* included from semantic-ui will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency gulp-concat@* included from semantic-ui will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency gulp-concat-css@* included from semantic-ui will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency gulp-copy@* included from semantic-ui will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency gulp-flatten@* included from semantic-ui will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency gulp-header@* included from semantic-ui will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency gulp-help@* included from semantic-ui will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency gulp-if@* included from semantic-ui will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency gulp-less@* included from semantic-ui will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency gulp-minify-css@* included from semantic-ui will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency gulp-notify@* included from semantic-ui will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency gulp-plumber@* included from semantic-ui will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency gulp-print@* included from semantic-ui will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency gulp-rename@* included from semantic-ui will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency gulp-replace@* included from semantic-ui will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency gulp-rtlcss@* included from semantic-ui will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency gulp-uglify@* included from semantic-ui will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency gulp-util@* included from semantic-ui will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency gulp-watch@* included from semantic-ui will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency map-stream@* included from semantic-ui will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency require-dot-file@* included from semantic-ui will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency yamljs@* included from semantic-ui will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN excluding symbolic link tests/withsymlinks/.hidden -> ../shown/.hidden                         
npm WARN excluding symbolic link tests/withsymlinks/bar.txt -> ../shown/bar.txt                         
npm WARN excluding symbolic link tests/withsymlinks/.hidden -> ../shown/.hidden                         
npm WARN excluding symbolic link tests/withsymlinks/bar.txt -> ../shown/bar.txt
```

Instead of simply:

```
npm WARN excluding symbolic link tests/withsymlinks/.hidden -> ../shown/.hidden                         
npm WARN excluding symbolic link tests/withsymlinks/bar.txt -> ../shown/bar.txt                         
npm WARN excluding symbolic link tests/withsymlinks/.hidden -> ../shown/.hidden                         
npm WARN excluding symbolic link tests/withsymlinks/bar.txt -> ../shown/bar.txt
```

which are the warning that the instructional video in the semantic-ui website suggests.

(I apologize for the long text)

After running it it does not do anything unless I Ctrl-C the process. I never reach the customization panel that the video in the following link gets to after running the command:

http://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html#using-build-tools

The link also suggested other methods of installing npm and node and I tried additional ones (always cleaning the system thoroughly before each attempt) and it seems that I install those correctly and with their paths inside the ~/.bashrc file. How shall I proceed?

Comment: Let it run, I also get those errors but its just a waiting game until everything is setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem happens because [npm will be changing the way peer dependencies work in version 3](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/110924823920/npm-weekly-5).

This issue [is also covered in Semantic UI issues](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/2086), but seems to be resolved now. Please try again and make sure you give it enough time (up to 10-15 minutes, though it should take less than that). If you still have problems, try to use the latest Semantic UI from the github repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI.git
cd Semantic-UI
npm install
```

This should have the same effect as running `npm install semantic-ui --save` so you'll get the interactive installer as soon as `npm install` finishes.