# Why installing Semantic UI via npm misses jQuery & throws an reference error to it?

Tags: jquery, node.js, windows, npm, semantic-ui

Hy,

I'm trying to install the CSS-Framework "Semantic UI" on a Windows 10 PC with npm from node.js.

I've followed the [official install-instructions](http://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html) carefully.

1. I've installed successful node.js (v4.0.0) with the [official Windows Installer](https://nodejs.org/en/).
2. Typed in Windows cmd `npm install -g gulp` to install [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) (npm v2.14.2).

   - First time I've got an error `ECONNRESET`, which I [could solve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419144/npm-not-working-read-econnreset). So gulp was successful installed globally.
3. At least I've tried several times to install Semantic UI with this code:

   `npm install semantic-ui --save
   cd semantic
   gulp build`

   Which does work halfway - [WARN peerdependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32212651/warn-peerdependencies-while-installing-semantic-ui) & the missing dependency package **jQuery** was the result. But I'm still able to build my fresh installed default Semantic UI Framework with `gulp build`.

I said *it works halfway* on my Windows 10 System, but also when I try to call my local file copy of the default template [Fixed Menu](http://semantic-ui.com/examples/fixed.html) I get in the google chrome developer tools following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined / semantic.min.js:11

Okay, it's just a unknown reference, but that pointed me to the missing jQuery package. After googling for it I've found a npm package [npm-install-missing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-install-missing) (best result for my predicament) and try it out in my project folder - nothing happend, because there is no **package.json** dependency-file.

So I went deeper in my given project structure by npm *"project folder\node_modules\semantic_ui* and ran it again. The result was a complete package update of every package in the *node_modules*-folder with enclosed **jQuery** package and some more: *github, gulp-concat-filenames, gulp-debug, gulp-git, gulp-json-editor, gulp-prompt, gulp-tap, merge-stream, mkdirp and wrench*. So 11 packages were missed due to the dependencies of Semantic UI.

But the **jQuery ReferenceError** is still available. When you try google chromes developer tools on the official [semantic-ui.com/](http://semantic-ui.com/), which is build with it's own framework, so you couldn't get any errors, although they put the *semantic.min.js* file in the same default directory-structure *dist/semantic.min.js*. Okay, my path has just one directory in front of: *semantic/dist/semantic.min.js* - but this is, how it's done in the official documentation.

Hopefully someone can help me to get this framework fully alive. :)

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: Upvoted just for how much detail you put in your question!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While jQuery is required by Semantic UI, it's not a npm requirement.

To clarify, jQuery is a client-side JavaScript Library. Using it requires you to include its .js file on your webpages inside a `<script>` tag. You can [download](https://jquery.com/download/) it from the official website or [use a CDN](https://code.jquery.com/).

The [jquery npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery) is related, but in no way the same thing. This package is used when you want to build your own jQuery file (i.e. when you want to make some changes or have some specific requirements) - you usually **don't** want to do this.

In short, if `gulp build` worked for you, then you're all set - the only two files you need are *semantic.css* and *semantic.js*. Make sure jQuery (found on jquery.com, *not* the one installed using npm) is also included in your web pages, right before semantic.js. So your "base" HTML file should look something like this (assuming the generated `semantic.css` and `semantic.js` are in the *dist* folder):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/semantic.css">
</head>

<body>
    Body goes here  

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/semantic.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @fstanis!
<br>
I see, I've to learn the basics first before using a advanced framework like Semantic UI and the dependent tools too. It saves a lot of time and nerves. ^^

Answer (score 1):

The problem may sit with node itself. And the reason may be because node insert extra symbol when jquery too want to insert the symbols with the same names

as specified here:
https://electronjs.org/docs/faq#i-can-not-use-jqueryrequirejsmeteorangularjs-in-electron

> Due to the Node.js integration of Electron, there are some extra
>   symbols inserted into the DOM like module, exports, require. This
>   causes problems for some libraries since they want to insert the
>   symbols with the same names.
>
> ........
>
> But if you want to keep the abilities of using Node.js and Electron
>   APIs, you have to rename the symbols in the page before including
>   other libraries:

```
    <head> <script> window.nodeRequire = require; delete window.require;
    > delete window.exports; delete window.module; </script> 
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
    </head>
```

**NOTE:** very important in your scripts after that renaming and delete of symbols. You need to use the new symbol. So in place of `require` you use `nodeRequire`. That will solve the problem. I was in the same problem, developing a desktop app using electron. And that solved it for me nice and neat. That's a common problem. In most all solutions depending on node.js. I had the same problem once with angular when i used bootstrap. Jquery didn't work. And that's the reason. And here is the solution.